# BBB: GPIO signal won't stay high

Tags: beagleboneblack, gpio

So I have a BeagleBone Black board, and I want to be able to set some `GPIO` pin from a `low` value to a `high` value.

For achieving this I'm using the `BlackLib`[1](http://blacklib.yigityuce.com/classBlackLib_1_1BlackGPIO.html) library (a C++ library that offers general access to all beaglebone's pins).

That library haves a class called `BlackGPIO` that offers the functionality that I want.

```
BlackLib::BlackGPIO NSLP_pin(BlackLib::GPIO_61, BlackLib::output, BlackLib::SecureMode);

auto NSLP_pinMode = NSLP_pin.getValue();

NSLP_pin.setValue(BlackLib::low);
```

I expect that this lines of code will set the signal from a `low` value to a `high` one (the signal is `low` by default).

The problem is that the signal goes `high` only for about `~10ms` (measured on a scope), and after that it goes `low` again.

What I do wrong?

How can I set the some `GPIO` pin at a certain value, and remain like that until I change it?

[1] [link](http://blacklib.yigityuce.com/classBlackLib_1_1BlackGPIO.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [link](http://www.armhf.com/using-beaglebone-black-gpios/) specifies to export the BBB pins from command line and to set it HIGH or LOW. You can develop a small C++ function to send those commands to kernel to export, ON/OFF the BBB pins. I'm using the same method in my C application and it works perfect.

Example code snippet in C to Enable the pin:

```
FILE *GPIO;
GPIO = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio65/direction", "w");
fseek(GPIO,0,SEEK_SET);
fprintf(GPIO,"61");
fflush(GPIO);
fclose(GPIO);
```